# Meteor 1.4.1 release not functional on Windows

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor

I tried to install Meteor on another system. Installation go well, then I copied my project and I am running meteor run but 
"Extracting meteor-tool@1.4.0-1" it is happening forever. Then I tried to update version number to 1.4.1 and run again "meteor run". Now I do not need to install 1.4.0.1 so it worked but got stuck on extracting on other modules.

Possible reasons can be extraction program of this is release is faulty. Would someone suggest a solution or how can I download 1.4.0.1 release of meteor directly?

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7688

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer of this problem. This is problem with tar extractor.
I installed the newest 7zip and renamed the tar.exe in my GIT program folder ("where tar" command in cmd revealed, that somehow that exe was associated with .tar archives) to tar.exe.old.
If you can not find where is tar then run "where tar" command to get path of tar.exe

This solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40122752/6861101

> Try adding the following to your local hosts file (C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts):
>
> `54.192.225.217 warehouse.meteor.com`
>
> Then run a `meteor reset` in your app directory (warning - will wipe your local DB), then try starting your app again.

This worked for me.