# Meteor stuck at Extracting meteor-tool@1.4.0-1

Tags: meteor

I am having an issue where I do meteor run in my project, and it begins to install meteor-tool@1.4.0-1, once it is 100%, it says

Extracting meteor-tool@1.4.0-1...

but it never finishes. I uninstalled meteor and reinstalled it but I am having the same issue.

United State.
Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your response, Vasil. I actually was able to find a solution and I am no longer experiencing this problem.

Turned out there was a problem with the tar.exe file in Git, and by uninstalling Git, and reinstalling it the latest version,  2.10.0.windows.1, the problem has seemed to go away.

It seemed that no matter how long I left it, it stayed stuck at "Extracting meteor-tools . . ." but now that I updated Git the problem has gone away.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem caused by the `tar` extractor provided by Git.

1. Find where is located the tar tool used by your system, running:

> `$ where tar`
>
> - In my case, it is located in `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\tar.exe`

2. Then locate the file and rename it to `tar.exe.old`
3. Its done... try running Meteor again! >> `$ meteor`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your local hosts file (C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts):

```
54.192.225.217 warehouse.meteor.com
```

Then run a `meteor reset` in your app directory (warning - will wipe your local DB), then try starting your app again.

This works for me.

Link: https://forums.meteor.com/t/downloading-meteor-tool-1-4-0-1/27269/19?u=lucianopestana